# Polars: Casting a Column to Decimal

Tags: python, pyspark, python-polars

I am trying to read a flat file, assign column names to the dataframe and cast few columns as per my requirements. However while casting a column to Decimal gives me error in Polars. I implemented the same successfully in Spark, but need help if anyone can guide me how to do the same in Polars.

sample data

```
D|120277|Patricia|167.2|26/12/1982
D|757773|Charles|167.66|08/04/2019 
D|248498|Katrina|168.68|20/11/2016 
D|325561|Christina|170.86|05/10/1998 
D|697464|Joshua|171.41|07/09/1970 
D|244750|Zachary|169.43|08/12/2014
```

Polar Script

```
import polars as pl

cols_dict = {'column_1': 'rtype', 'column_2': 'EMP_ID', 'column_3': 'EMP_NAME', 'column_4': 'SALARY', 'column_5': 'DOB'}

df = pl.read_csv(data_file, separator='|'), has_header=False)
df = df.select(pl.all().map_alias(lambda col_name: cols_dict.get(col_name)))

df = df.with_columns(
pl.col('EMP_ID').cast(pl.Decimal(scale=6, precision=0)))
```

It throws me exception:

`exceptions.ComputeError: strict conversion from` i64`to`decimal[0,6]`failed for value(s) \[......\]; if you were trying to cast Utf8 to temporal dtypes, consider using`strptime``

Spark Script:

```
rdd = sparkContext.textFile(core_data_file).filter(lambda x: x\[0\] == "D").map(
lambda x: x.split('|'))

sparkDf= rdd.toDF(schema=\["rtype"\] + list(cols_dict .values()))
sparkDf= sparkDf.withColumn(col_name, coalesce(
col(col_name).cast(DecimalType(data_length, data_scale)), lit(0)))
sarkDf.show()
```

```
+-----+------+---------+------+-------------------+
|rtype|EMP_ID|EMP_NAME |SALARY|DOB                |
+-----+------+---------+------+-------------------+
|D    |120277|Patricia |167.20|1982-12-26 00:00:00|
|D    |757773|Charles  |167.66|2019-04-08 00:00:00|
|D    |248498|Katrina  |168.68|2016-11-20 00:00:00|
|D    |325561|Christina|170.86|1998-10-05 00:00:00|
|D    |697464|Joshua   |171.41|1970-09-07 00:00:00|
|D    |244750|Zachary  |169.43|2014-12-08 00:00:00|
+-----+------+---------+------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `scale` and `precision` parameters are invalid. `scale` specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, while `precision` specifies the total number of digits in the number. Setting `precision = 0` is invalid. If you want 6 decimals, then rewrite precision as:

```py
pl.col('EMP_ID').cast(pl.Decimal(scale=6, precision=None)))
```

I noticed that `pl.Decimal` is an "*experimental work-in-progress feature and may not work as expected*" [Polars docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Decimal.html). An alternative is to use `pl.Float64` instead:

```py
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('EMP_ID').cast(pl.Float64))
```

Answer (score 1):

In polars `precision` and `scale` are reversed from most other SQL-like definitions.

In your Spark code, the [DecimalType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType.html) is expecting a `precision` then `scale`.

```py
col(col_name).cast(DecimalType(data_length, data_scale))
```

However, because the polars [Decimal](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Decimal.html) has a default of `None` for `precision`, and no default for `scale`, the order is reversed.

```py
# A decimal[6,0]
pl.Decimal(0, 6)
pl.Decimal(scale=0, precision=6)
```

If the decimal configuration is enabled, and `precision` and `scale` are set appropriately, the cast will work.

```py
pl.Config(activate_decimals = True)
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("EMP_ID").cast(pl.Decimal(precision=6, scale=0)))

print(df)
```

```
shape: (6, 5)
┌───────┬──────────────┬───────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ rtype ┆ EMP_ID       ┆ EMP_NAME  ┆ SALARY ┆ DOB         │
│ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ str   ┆ decimal[6,0] ┆ str       ┆ f64    ┆ str         │
╞═══════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ D     ┆ 120277       ┆ Patricia  ┆ 167.2  ┆ 26/12/1982  │
│ D     ┆ 757773       ┆ Charles   ┆ 167.66 ┆ 08/04/2019  │
│ D     ┆ 248498       ┆ Katrina   ┆ 168.68 ┆ 20/11/2016  │
│ D     ┆ 325561       ┆ Christina ┆ 170.86 ┆ 05/10/1998  │
│ D     ┆ 697464       ┆ Joshua    ┆ 171.41 ┆ 07/09/1970  │
│ D     ┆ 244750       ┆ Zachary   ┆ 169.43 ┆ 08/12/2014  │
└───────┴──────────────┴───────────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```